# Creating 12 month MA in PyCaret time series gives a column with NA values

Tags: python, time-series, moving-average, pycaret

I am trying to use `PyCaret` for time series, according to [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-forecasting-with-pycaret-regression-module-237b703a0c63).
My analysis did not work. When I created a new column

`data['MA12'] = data['variable'].rolling(12).mean()`

I got this new `MA12` column with `NA` values only.

As a resulted I decided to replicate the code from the tutorial, using `AirPassangers` dataset, but got the same issue.

When I print data, I get

```
Month   Passengers  MA12
0   1949-01-01  112 NaN
1   1949-02-01  118 NaN
2   1949-03-01  132 NaN
3   1949-04-01  129 NaN
4   1949-05-01  121 NaN
```

I would greatly appreciate any tips on what is going on here.

My only guess, I use a default version of `PyCaret`, maybe I need to install a full one. Tried this too - the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the previous 12 reads, the first 11 will be NaN. You need more rows than 12 before you get a moving average of 12. You can see this on the link you provided. The chart of MA doesn't start up right away.